# How can i create a delegate and pass it as a parameter in one line

Tags: c, delegates

I have implemented a `List` and i have also implemented a `ForEach` Method for easier iteration.

```
typedef struct node
{
    struct node* NextNode;
    void* Data;
} Node;

typedef struct list
{
    Node* Head;
    Node* Tail;
    int Length;
} List;

void ListForEach(List* list, void(*iteratorDelegate)(Node*))
{
    Node* actual = list->Head;
    while (actual)
    {
        iteratorDelegate(actual);
        actual = actual->NextNode;
    }
}

Node* NodeNew(void* data)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->NextNode = NULL;
    node->Data = data;
    return node;
}

List* ListNew()
{
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->Head = NULL;
    list->Tail = NULL;
    list->Length = 0;
    return list;
}
```

My Testprogramm looks like this:

```
void PrintDelegate(Node* node)
{
    printf("Data: %d\n", (int)node->Data);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    List* list = ListNew();
    int counter = 0;
    for (counter; counter != 500000; counter++)
    {
        ListAdd(list, NodeNew((void*)counter));
    }

    ListForEach(list, PrintDelegate);
}
```

But the use of `ListForEach` feels very unhandy because i always have to create a new method. Is there a easier way to delegate a method?
In **C#** i would do:

```
ListForEach(list, (node) => printf("Data: %d\n", (int)node.Data));
```

This also creates a delegate but i don't need to declare a new method in the class / global scope.

Is something like this also possible in **C**?

Comment: You are talking about lambda-functions. There is no such a thing in C.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes right. i am talking about lambda-functions. But i thought there is a workaround which does not need a explicit implementation of the method.

Comment: The ***[closest thing to C# delegates in C are function pointers](https://www.google.com/#q=What+is+a+delegate+in+C)***.

Answer (score 1):

The C language does not have lambda functions.  However, C++ does support it starting in C++11.

So if you're willing the make the switch, you could do something like this:

```
ListForEach(list, 
    [](Node* node) {
        printf("Data: %d\n", (int)node->Data);
    } // end of lambda expression
);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. That's really nice to know, but it does not really help me because i have not the possibility to switch to C++ :(

Answer (score 1):

Definition from Google search "What is a delegate in C":

> A delegate in C# is similar to a *function pointer* in C or C++. Using a
>   delegate allows the programmer to encapsulate a reference to a method
>   inside a delegate object. The delegate object can then be passed to
>   code which can call the referenced method, without having to know at
>   compile time which method will be invoked.

*emphasis mine*

The concept of *delegates* does not exist natively in C.  The closest thing in C is *function pointers*.  Using a function pointer, you can define several methods to be pointed to, but defer actual method selection until run-time. (i.e., you do not have to know which method will be used at compile-time.)

A simple function pointer example:

```
enum {
    ADD,
    SUB,
    MULT,
    DIV,
    OP_MAX
};

typedef float (*pOperation)(float x, float y);

pOperation Op[OP_MAX] = {0}; //create function pointer using typedef

//prototype various functions to use function pointer
float add(float x, float y);
float sub(float x, float y);
float mult(float x, float y);
float div(float x, float y);

int main(void)
{
    float res = 0;
    int i;

    //tie "delegate" to various implementations 
    Op[ADD] = &add;
    Op[SUB] = &sub;
    Op[MULT] = &mult;
    Op[DIV] = &div;

    for(i=ADD;i<OP_MAX;i++)
    {
        //here, Op is used as a delegate for each of the 4 basic arithmetic functions: 
        res = Op[i](3, 7); //performs 4 basic arithmetic functions

        //From definition above: The delegate object can 
        //be passed to code which can call the referenced method, 
        //without having to know at compile time which method 
        //will be invoked
    }

    return 0;
}

//implementations
float add(float x, float y){return x + y;}
float sub(float x, float y){return x - y;}
float mult(float x, float y){return x * y;}
float div(float x, float y){return x / y;}
```

`ListForEach(list, PrintDelegate);` could perhaps be implemented in a similar fashion (using function pointers) to accomplish what you need to do.